# window command prompt for searching

Tags: command, prompt

When you use window and go to a folder, there will be a search box and when you write something there, windows will automatically search the folder and all subfolders inside it for the keyword (it searches the title and the content of all documents also).

I just wonder if there is a way to perform that similar action but in command prompt (I want to search all types of file: pdf, txt,...)

I have tried **find** and **findstr** but findstr only searches text file and for find it returns wrong result for me. Because I know for sure that for example the word 'dangerous' is in a document but the result from **find** is 0

Answer (score -1):

Do you want it to search the filenames for the keyword or the actual contents of the file? In such case i think you will need to write a simple c++ program to stream the data of each file and search for the keyword that way

Comment: Hi, I want to search the content of the files. i have not used C++ before, can you give me some reference page?. Thank you.

Comment: and also can the C++ code search also in the pdf file, doc file,... I mean in all kind of file or only the text file